# Php Curl https URLs very slow

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https

i have some troubles with curl request in php.
When i send a GET request in php with curl or directly with curl i have similar response time for http url.

For example, about one HTTP URL, i have between 90 and 100ms response time.

But for all HTTPs URLs, for 100 ms real response time i receive 1 second if i send request curl with a php script (ten times more!). I made many test about URLs which are really faster with all another tool.
I have this problem just with https Protocol.

I can understand that php requests are more slowly than another language but ten times more is really a lot i think there is a problem.

This is the code i use :

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.website.tld';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0; en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101');
curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo 'Response time : ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds';
curl_close($ch);
```

I test also to verify SSL but that doesn't change the response time.
Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Is it any faster if you use the IP of the website with a host header? This will help to locate a DNS lookup issue. Can you include more of the `curl_getinfo` info in your question.

Comment: curl_getinfo contains a lot more info than just the total time, do `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` to get them all. you're not providing enough info to identify the culprit. for example, how much time is spent with DNS lookup? CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME  would tell you, which is part of curl_getinfo.